# Swagger: как указать ссылку ра респонс для выбора необходимого варианта

Tags: api, rest, swagger

Интересует вопрос: возможно ли в Swagger указать ссылку для респонса тела и выбора нужного варианта в зависимости от полученного ответа?

Мне на каждый успешный запрос API отвечает 200, далее в теле приходит json который содержит result: 0 - значит все ок, и дополнительные данные.

Если приходит != 0, то это ошибка от 1 до 100, без описания.

Могу ли я в swagger сделать так: если в ответе пришел result :0 то отобрази схему - "описание схемы".

Если result : !=0, то выбери схему из (далее ссылка) #ref error

error:

- result :1
  описание
- result :2
  описание
  ...
  описание
- result 100
  описание

Описывать одно и тоже в каждом запросе как-то громоздко и не читабельно...

Как сделано сейчас:

```
responses:
    '200':
      description: Успешный ответ от сервера
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: "#/components/schemas/ureg_responses"
            type: object
            properties:
              result:
                type: integer
              uuid:
                type: string
                
    'result: 1':
      description: ERROR_UNKNOWN
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: "#/components/schemas/result_1"
            type: object
            properties:
              result:
                type: integer
    
    'result: 12':
      description: fname or sname format mismatch
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: "#/components/schemas/result_12"
            type: object
            properties:
              result:
                type: integer
    
    
    'result: 21':
      description: uphone format mismatch
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: "#/components/schemas/result_21"
            type: object
            properties:
              result:
                type: integer
```

Не хотелось бы все это описывать для каждого запроса...